# How does one load a .mat file in the GUI, matlab app development

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am attempting to create a MATLAB app that saves the specific fields in a .mat file and allows for custom naming. Saving has seemed to work however attempting to load leads to nothing changing.
Any help would be appreciated

```
function SaveButtonPushed(app, event) % Saving element
            
            props = properties(app);
            lp    = length(props);
            values   = cell(1,lp);
            visibilities   = cell(1,lp);
            
            for i = 1:lp
                propName = props{1};
                property = app.(propName);
                if isprop(property, 'Value')
                    values{i} = app.(propName).Value;
                end
%                 if isprop(property, 'Visible')
%                     visibilities{i} = app.(props{i}).Visible;
%                 end
            end
            
            
            file = uiputfile('*.mat', "Save Message" );
            
            if file
                save(file, 'props', 'values', 'visibilities');
            end
end
function LoadButtonPushed(app, event) % Loading element
            [file,path] = uigetfile('*.mat');
            selectedfile = fullfile(file);
            load(selectedfile)
end
```

Comment: you call `load` and then exit the function, all variables you loaded were in the workspace for the `LoadButtonPushed` function and are not visible to the app when that function exits - what do you expect to happen with those variables? Did you add a breakpoint and step through this function to see what's happening?

Comment: You can define an app  `property` and then assign to it the data loaded in the `LoadButtonPushed` callback.

Answer (score 0):

It is like Wolfie said in his comment. The variables in the `.mat` file are loaded into the private workspace for that function, which is cleared at once it exits.

So within the function you should be able to loop over your app properties again and set the values the ones loaded from the file.

Note that if you add a breakpoint, as Wolfie says, you should be able to see the private workspace and your loaded variables will be there until the function exits.

Alternatively, you could load the variables in to a structure:

```
S = load(selectedfile);
```

(See https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html for more details)
and return that structure,

```
function [S] = LoadButtonPushed(app, event) % Loading element
```

You will have to change the interface/load function call to accept the returned variable, and I'm not sure that you can add the contents of the structure to the global namespace. However, you can access them through the loaded structure as:

```
S.props
```

Comment: `return S;` is an invalid statement: The output of a function are listed in the definition of the function (e. g. `function out_param=function_name(input_param)`)

Comment: Except that `LoadButtonPushed` is a callback, its return values are ignored. The first half of your answer is good.